# How to setup Mule ESB SFTP listener

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

How do I setup an SFTP (ssh) listener on Mule ESB (CE)?

I could only find the HTTP(S) listener)

Thank you for any hints

Answer (score 1):

MuleESB/ Mule Runtime is not SFTP server. All you can do is using mule SFTP connector pull and push the files (SFTP Client). If you are looking for SFTP server need to host. If your partner company have option to send data over HTTP(S) you could use mule HTTP Listener.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate connector same connector can be used for `username-password` and `publickey`. Please refer [preferredAuthenticationMethods attribute](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/sftp-transport-reference#attributes-of-the-connector-element) for more details. Configuration will be like

```
<sftp:connector name="SFTP" identityFile="ppkOrpemfile_path" preferredAuthenticationMethods="publickey" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SFTP"/>
<flow name="testSFTP_flow">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="host" port="22"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this is a connector to an external SFTP server? I need to have my partners connect to my Mule ESB using SFTP. Therefore I need Mule ESB to listen on port 22 (or another port).

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out wrapper.conf file from your server's conf folder.
Modify the port no

wrapper.java.additional.=-Dmule.mmc.bind.port=7779